# SharePoint Designer 2013 Email Workflow On SharePoint 365/Online Include List of Files Under Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-set, sharepoint-email

I have a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow on my SharePoint Online site that sends an email based on a metadata trigger linked to a Document Set with an choice 'Action' column - it works fairly well. One thing though I'd like is for the email to include a list of the document filenames that are under the Document Set (just the file names, not attaching the files). Not sure how to go about getting this and if anyone can help would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved by using SharePoint 2013 Workflow. Have you ever considered using Microsoft Power Automate flow as an alternative? We can get file names in a document set using the action "**Get files(properties only)**" and limiting entries to the document set.

[image]

Then we can import file names we get into emails.
[image]